# Retrieve value from Hashmap using partial key

Tags: rust, hashmap

I have a HashMap with key type `(i64,usize)`

Suppose I have an use case to retrieve data from this HashMap using only first part of Key tuple.

For example I have sample data like this

```
(-1, 1): "1st -1 Resident", 
(1, 1): "1st 1 Resident", 
(1, 0): "Oth 1 Resident", 
(1, 2): "2nd 1 Resident", 
(-1, 2): "2nd -1 Resident", 
(-1, 0): "Oth -1 Resident"
```

I want to retrieve or operate on all data with `-1` as the first entry of key tuple. Or in terms of the above example, all residents of `-1`.
I'm currently doing this, looping over all entries in Hashmap and manually checking the first part of key tuple.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main(){
    let mut hmap: HashMap<(i64,usize), &str> = HashMap::new();
    hmap.insert((-1,0), "Oth -1 Resident");
    hmap.insert((-1,1), "1st -1 Resident");
    hmap.insert((-1,2), "2nd -1 Resident");
    
    hmap.insert((1,0), "Oth 1 Resident");
    hmap.insert((1,1), "1st 1 Resident");
    hmap.insert((1,2), "2nd 1 Resident");

    for (k,v) in &hmap {
        if k.0 == -1 {
            println!("{:?}",v);
        } 
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to do this?
Here is the link to my current work ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=44459ebb069743cddf9700773d4b6478))

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d89ea0efd40cc1b31c860a0e90e62c43 but BTreeMap is an interesting solution see what is best for your use case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any better way to do this?

Not with a hashmap, as an entry is localised by a hash of the *entire* key there is no partial matching possible.

However it would be possible using a [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html): a BTreeMap's entries are positioned based on *ordering* of the keys, so you can [iterate a subset based off of a range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.range), which also works as a prefix match / search (that is why e.g. database indexes use btrees by default, it provides for more flexible querying than hashes).

Here you can request the range starting at `(-1, usize::MIN)` inclusive and ending at `(0, usize::MIN)` exclusive, and it'll give you all the entries whose key starts with `-1`.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2a78568fa2870afa949919075d7c3579

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn main(){
    let mut hmap: BTreeMap<(i64,usize), &str> = BTreeMap::new();
    hmap.insert((-1,0), "Oth -1 Resident");
    hmap.insert((-1,1), "1st -1 Resident");
    hmap.insert((-1,2), "2nd -1 Resident");
    
    hmap.insert((1,0), "Oth 1 Resident");
    hmap.insert((1,1), "1st 1 Resident");
    hmap.insert((1,2), "2nd 1 Resident");

    for (k,v) in hmap.range((-1, usize::MIN)..(0, usize::MIN)) {
        println!("{k:?} {v}");
    }
}
```

output:

```
(-1, 0) Oth -1 Resident
(-1, 1) 1st -1 Resident
(-1, 2) 2nd -1 Resident
```